# How can I perform NIntegrate with NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm a new user and I have no idea how to perform NIntegrate by using NDSolve. For example consider following differential equation (DE):

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] + 2/t y'[t] == 10 y[t], y[10] == 10, y'[10] == 0}, 
  y[t], {t, 0, 10^9}, SolveDelayed -> True]

NIntegrate[t^2 y[t]/.sol , {t, 0, 10^5}]
```

Comment: The solution to your ODE is  `y(t)=0`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem with your code except that Mma seems to be confused with the expression `2/t y'[t]`. It is better to rewrite it as `2*y'[t]/t`. After that this

```
    sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] + 2* y'[t]/t - 10 y[t] == 0, y[10] == 10, 
   y'[10] == 0}, y[t], {t, 1, 10}]
```

returns an interpolation function as a solution. It can be looked at:

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol], {t, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

ans also integrated:

```
 NIntegrate[Evaluate[t^2 y[t] /. sol], {t, 1, 10}]

(*  {4.61938*10^13}  *)
```

It is to be noted that the solution diverges at `t->0`. It is for this reason I started from 1. And the result of the integration is huge, even in my reduced limits. But, may be, it is OK with you.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Your example DE is simple enough for DSolve to show that y[t]==0. That probably isn't what you wanted, or that might be the reason your results don't seem correct.

Let's try another example.

```
sol = y[t] /. NDSolve[{y'[t]==y[t], y[0]==1}, y[t], {t, 0, 10}][[1]];
NIntegrate[sol, {t, 0, 6}]
```

which gives you 402.429 while

```
Integrate[E^t, {t, 0, 6}] // N
```

also gives you 402.429.

Perhaps you can adapt this to your real problem.