# How can I combine NIntegrate with NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have no idea how to calculate the problems. 
For example consider following differential equation (DE):

```
NDSolve[{x''[t] + 2/t x'[t] == (x[t])^2 + (x[t])^4 + 34, 
    x[∞] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, ∞}][[1]];
NIntegrate[(t^2)[1/2 (x'[t])^2 + (x[t])^2], {t, 0, ∞}]
```

It is very troubled to quantum tunnelling problem.
Please tell me how to calculate it.

Comment: is this different than your other question [how-can-i-perform-nintegrate-with-ndsolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101784/how-can-i-perform-nintegrate-with-ndsolve) ?

Comment: I feel like this isn't really a problem of getting `NIntegrate` and `NDSolve` to play nice together (because really that's not too hard). Rather, it seems to me that you're not even getting a solution to your differential equation. Concentrate on *that* first.

Answer (score 4):

This problem does not appear to have a solution.  If `x[t]` is to vanish at large `t`, then it must satisfy

```
x''[t] + 2/t x'[t] == 34
```

approximately at large `t`.  The solution to this equation is

```
First@DSolve[x''[t] + 2/t x'[t] == 34, x[t], t]
(* {x[t] -> (17 t^2)/3 - C[1]/t + C[2]} *)
```

For no values of the two constants does this solution approach zero as `t` approaches ∞.